# I have a problem with my . in calculator. I need to have just one dot

Tags: javascript, html, css

Need to have only one dot, so a calculator can work properly. Not lots of dots like I have now. Now it's a mess. I will work on 
 other stuff in code later, but now I'm stuck here.

```
 function dec(d) {

      let display = document.getElementById('display');
      let displayArray = display.innerHTML.split("");
      displayArray += d.innerHTML;
      display.innerHTML = displayArray;
      if (!displayArray.includes(".")) {
          displayArray += ".";
          displayArray = display;
      }
```

I have tried some stuff and now I'm nowhere with this.

I need to have normal, just one dot and now because of the array I
 have 
      ",." on every "." I click

I now that the problem is somewhere in 
     doing something with an array, split array or something but don't 
     know where exactly is the problem.

Comment: `displayArray` will be an `array`. This line `displayArray += d.innerHTML;` is not making any sense

Comment: can you provide working fiddle

Comment: Also, you first add a dot to `displayArray`, and then you replace the entire `displayArray` with `display`. That can't be right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with concatination of array with string

```
displayArray += d.innerHTML;
```

string conversion/toString of an array by default joins all the elements with ','

if you want any other separator you will have to define it

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4]
console.log(array+'')
console.log(array.join())
console.log(array.toString())
//Correct one
console.log(array.join(''))
```

So your code must be

```
displayArray = displayArray.join('') + d.innerHTML;
```

However displayArray will no more be an *Array* but a *String*

Comment: now this not working because Invalid left hand side of the assignment - That is saying on the line with .join("")

function dec(d) {

  let display = document.getElementById('display');
  let displayArray = display.innerHTML.split("");
  displayArray.join("") += d.innerHTML;
  display.innerHTML = displayArray;
  if (!displayArray.includes(".")) {
      displayArray += ".";
      displayArray = display;
  }

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>


  <script src="script.js"></script>



    <table class="main" id="gradient">
      <tr class="row">
        <th class="column displayValue" id="display">0</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <th class="buttons bckbtn" onclick="clearAll()">C</th>
        <th class="buttons bckbtn" onclick="backbutton(this)">backspace</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <th class="buttons" onclick="numbers(this)">7</th>
        <th class="buttons" onclick="numbers(this)">8</th>
        <th class="buttons" onclick="numbers(this)">9</th>
        <th class="buttons">/</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <th class="buttons" onclick="numbers(this)">4</th>
        <th class="buttons" onclick="numbers(this)">5</th>
        <th class="buttons" onclick="numbers(this)">6</th>
        <th class="buttons">x</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <th class="buttons" onclick="numbers(this)">1</th>
        <th class="buttons" onclick="numbers(this)">2</th>
        <th class="buttons" onclick="numbers(this)">3</th>
        <th class="buttons" onclick="numbers(this)">-</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <th class="buttons" id="decimal" onclick="dec(this)">.</th>
        <th class="buttons" onclick="numbers(this)">0</th>
        <th class="buttons" onclick="numbers(this)">=</th>
        <th class="buttons" onclick="numbers(this)">+</th>
      </tr>
    </table>


  </body>
</html>



function numbers(el) {

  let display = document.getElementById('display');

  if (display.innerHTML === "0") {
   display.innerHTML = "";
   display.innerHTML += el.innerHTML;
  }
  else {
    display.innerHTML += el.innerHTML;
  }
}


function clearAll() {

  let display = document.getElementById('display');
  display.innerHTML = "0";

}


function backbutton(b) {

  let display = document.getElementById('display');
  let value = display.innerHTML;
  let newValue = value.substr(0, value.length - 1);
  display.innerHTML = newValue;
  if (display.innerHTML === "") {
    display.innerHTML = "0";
  }
  document.getElementById("decimal").setAttribute("onclick", "dec(this)");

}


function dec(d) {

  let display = document.getElementById('display');
  let displayArray = display.innerHTML.split("");
  displayArray.join("") += d.innerHTML;
  display.innerHTML = displayArray;
  if (!displayArray.includes(".")) {
      displayArray += ".";
      displayArray = display;
  }

}
```